# text files location after tomcat deployement

Tags: java, file, tomcat, tomcat7, web-deployment

Please i'm using text files to do some processing in my web app,

But when i'm deploying on tomcat the path is changed and i'm not able to access my file anymore

My structure is as follow

[image: [project structure]

src contains java classes and files contains the files i want to access.

i'm accessing it before deployment with the following path:

```
String filePath="files/P1.txt";
```

But after deployment i can no longer have access to files,

How can i define the path so it will be functional after deployment?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `P1.txt` is directly under `files/` which is as far as I can see in your image attached marked as a source directory and I expect that the file should be located in the classpath's root and can be accessed without `files/` path segment. To read files from the classpath you need to find the Classloader:

```
class MyClass {
   public void readFile() {
    // ... some logic
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("P1.txt");
    // ... some logic with the stream.
   }
}
```

In order to verify the files in the classpath and also for debugging purposes, you can list all the files within the classpath:

```
Enumeration<URL> rootFiles = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("");
```

An empty String passed to the `getResources` method gives the files and directories in the classpath's root. You should be able to see your file there.